# how to perform multiprocessing inside Azure API run function

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am trying to reduce the execution time of an API call by using multiprocessing:

My original requirement is actually on generating and displaying ML explainability using LIME. For simplicity, let's assume I have below data:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id' : ['id1','id1','id2','id2','id2','id1','id2','id1','id1','id2'],
                      'prod_id' : ['p1','p2','p3','p1','p4','p5','p6','p6','p8','p9'],
                      'cost' : np.random.randint(100, 1000, 10)})
```

We have another dataframe:

```py
 df1 = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id' : ['id1','id1','id1','id2','id2','id2'],
                       'prod_id' : ['p1','p8','p3','p8','p9','p7']})
```

My API function looks something like this:

```py
import json

def main(data):
    input_data = json.loads(data)["data"]
    customer_id = input_data[0]
    print(customer_id)
    item_list = df1.loc[df1["cust_id"] == customer_id, "prod_id"].tolist()

    idx = df.loc[
        (df["cust_id"] == customer_id) & (df["prod_id"].isin(item_list))
    ].index.values.tolist()

    for i in idx:
        df.loc[i, "cost"] = df.loc[i, "cost"] * 2

    return df
```

The input is in `json` format:

```py
data = '{"data":["id1"]}'

out = main(data)
```

My actual code consists of this inplace of the multiplication:

```py
explainer.explain_instance(df.loc[idx], model.predict_proba)
```

In actual scenario, the for loop would run for 24 times, fetching the row and putting it in the `explain_instance`.

Could someone please let me know how to perform multiprocessing of the for loop such that the 24 iterations come down as much as possible. I have 12 CPU cores in my actual instance.

Comment: Hi, are you feeding `explain_instance` a whole row (df.loc[idx]) or only a value, like in your example (df.loc[i, 'cost'])?

Comment: @Laurent, on the whole row. And that row is input to the XGBOOST model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) class and [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function from Python standard library's [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures) and [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) modules:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def helper(row, explainer=None, predict_fn=None):
    """Function that will be applied concurrently"""
    df_ = pd.DataFrame(explainer(row, predict_fn))
    # do things with df_
    # ...
    return df_


def main(data):
    # Same code as before your for-loop
    input_data = json.loads(data)["data"]
    customer_id = input_data[0]
    item_list = df1.loc[df1["cust_id"] == customer_id, "prod_id"].tolist()

    idx = df.loc[
        (df["cust_id"] == customer_id) & (df["prod_id"].isin(item_list))
    ].index.values.tolist()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # Here, you need partial to deal with additional arguments:
        # explainer, predict_fn
        future = executor.map(
            partial(
                helper,
                explainer=explainer.explain_instance,
                predict_fn=model.predict_proba,
            ),
            [df.loc[i] for i in idx],
        )

    # future is a generator
    return list(future)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = '{"data":["id1"]}'
    dfs = main(data)  # list of dataframes
```

You have to execute the module in the [top-level code environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) (using *if __name__ == "__main__"*), otherwise a [BrokenProcessPool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool) exception will be raised.

Comment: I actually need to perform additional tasks after `explainer.instance` like create a dataframe from that output perform certain data wrangling tasks, can I do that inside the `executor.map` function? also could you please let me know why you've mentioned `id1` here: `data = '{"data":["id1"]}'`

Comment: So the input to the API would a `json` : `'{"data":["abc"]}`, which would then be fed into `input_data = json.loads(data)["data"]`. When I try the same using above code, I get this error: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` for this line `dfs = main(data)`

Comment: Sorry, my updated answer contained unnecessary quotation marks ("explainer.explain_instance" instead of explainer.explain_instance, "model.predict_proba" instead of model.predict_proba), hence the exception. This is fixed now.